# quicksort implementation with partitioning around the median in c++

Tags: c++, quicksort, partitioning

I struggled to solve this issue by myself but it made me more confused. I look at those sample codes for quicksort that used the median to do partition on it, and I tried it on one sample array say A={1,8,4,6,7,10,11} and I did not get the correct partitioning. The code for partition is below:

```
void swap(int &x, int &y){
    int temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
 }
//
int partition(int arr[],int low,int high){
int pivot=arr[(low+high)/2];
while(low<=high){
   while(arr[low]<pivot) low++;
   while(arr[high]>pivot) high--;
   if(low<=high){
      swap(arr[low],arr[high]);
      low++;
      high--;
    }
 }
 return low;
}
```

For my example pivot is 6 so the code first swaps 8 and 6 in the array A ,and then stops. It does not put all smaller values than pivot=6 before that and large ones above. I guess the issue is we assume that we can always find two values from the left and right side of pivot to swap, but this example the right side is fine. Any comments or idea will be appreciated.
Just few updates: (1) my focus here is on the partition part of quick sort and I am aware of the following steps doing a recursive method.(2) I saw this methods in many links even in this website 
[Quick Sort - Middle Pivot implementation strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837737/quick-sort-middle-pivot-implementation-strange-behaviour)
(or in the "cracking the coding interview" book, page. 119 written in java)and they claim it works but I doubt it (I mean the partition part, it might somehow end up with a sorted array for any reason but a correct partition has to implemented such that all numbers that are less than the partitioning element come before all elements that are greater than it.) In my sample array A it ends up A={1,6,4,8,7,10,11} which is not a correct partition since 4 is after 6(our pivot).

Comment: Everything is fine. After the first partition, you continue recursively with two subarrays, `A1 = {1, 6, 4}` and `A2 = {8, 7, 10, 11}`

Comment: Your pivot is not the median, it's the middle of the array. (Using the median without sorting the entire array first is difficult.)

Comment: @OlafDietsche Quicksort partitioning isn't recursive.

Comment: You have not completed your code. You have only implemented partition, which is invoked by quick_sort(), followed by  left and right side recursive quick_sort() invocations.

Comment: Partitioning is not supposed to put all values lower than 6 before the 6. It's supposed to put everything <= 6 on the left side, and everything > 6 on the right side *in any order* and return the first index of the right side. It returns 3, the index of the 8 after swapping, and all the values in elements 0, 1, and 2 are <= 6.

Comment: @Jason Bad wording on my side, sorry. A better wording might be "..., you continue *sorting* recursively with two subarrays, ...". Though, I think everybody dealing with Quicksort is aware, that partitioning is only a part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There are some obvious bugs in your partition implementation.  One of the bigger ones is that you don't re-compare the element you `swap` in.

When you partition in Quicksort, you only need to move elements larger than the pivot, after the pivot element.  So, a simple implementation would be...

```
int partition(int arr[], int begin, int end) {

  int pivot = arr[begin + ((end - begin) / 2)];

  while (begin != end) {

    if (arr[begin] < pivot)
      begin++;
    else
      swap(arr[begin], arr[end--]);
  }

  return end;
}
```

Note, the complexity depends on the quality of the pivot, which is why a median would be ideal.  However, this would require iterating over all of the elements `O(n)`.

Keep in mind, picking the middle of the array won't always give a good pivot.  There are a few strategies for picking a good pivot (randomizing, sample and median, and so on...).

Comment: Choosing the middle element does mean that a quick sort on an already sorted or reverse sorted array isn't worse case.

Comment: Right, the ideal is picking the median.  Picking `max` or `min` are worst case partitions.

Comment: @Jason thanks for your comment, your code does what it expects to do but I am not sure is the efficient way to do partitioning the array around the pivot since you bring elements from the right side of pivot to the left without checking if it is larger or smaller. Of course, you check it again in the left side since begin index does not move forward until to do a comparison with pivot, but it wastes time to bring a larger value from right to left and then put it back.

Comment: @hjavan It's only an example to demonstrate what a correct partition using the center element would do.  Avoiding unnecessary moves is also only a constant factor optimization.  You should optimize complexity first (e.g. random pivot, multiple pivot, sample, etc...).  Optimization doesn't matter if your algorithm isn't correct though.